# Dispatch values to redux action are not updated in order react app

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

I'm writing an app to keep track of time for DnD, and I'm facing an issue with the order that the values are updated and the values that are passed to the dispatch action to update the data base.

This is my component

```
//Redux
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { updateTime } from "../../Redux/actions/timeActions";

//Styles
import "./TimeButtons.css";

const TimeButtons = () => {
  const { gmDay, gmTime } = useSelector((state) => state.time);

  const [day, setDay] = useState(gmDay);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(gmTime);

  console.log(day, time);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  if (time > 23) {
    setTime(0);
    setDay(day + 1);
  }

  const handleTime = (value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 1:
        setTime(time + 1);
        break;
      case 3:
        setTime(time + 3);
        break;
      case 8:
        setTime(time + 8);
        break;
      case 24:
        setTime(0);
        setDay(day + 1);
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Error");
    }

    dispatch(updateTime(day, time));
  };

  return (
    <div className="timeButtons">
      <div className="timeButtons__row 1">
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(1)}>
          1 Hour
        </button>
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(3)}>
          3 Hour
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="timeButtons__row 2">
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(8)}>
          8 Hour
        </button>
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(24)}>
          Next day
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TimeButtons;
```

Basically what happens is when I press any of the buttons it should update the variables day and time, and then dispatch that value to my action that has a call to my server, but what is happening is, it sends the previews values that are in the variables before they are updated....

so if let's say day = 1 and time = 4.... if  I press add 1 hour, instead of sending day=1 time= 5 it sends day = 1 and time= 4, it then updates the variables but it does not pass the correct value to the dispatch, so it's always one value behind

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but I'm fairly new to coding and it's killing some of my brain cells

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer the question as it is posed but I could give you deeper advice if I understood what `updateTime` was doing.  How is the date stored when you interact with the server?  Is it an object like `{gmDay: 5, gmTime: 7}` or is it a timestamp?  I think that you can use [Javascript date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to handle certain edge cases.  For example, what if `gmDay` is 31 and we click "Next day"?  We probably want `gmDay` to be 1 instead of 32.

One option is to move all of the logic into redux and just `dispatch(increaseHours(3))`.  Another option is to select a complete date `string` or `number` from Redux, perform operations on it, and `dispatch` an `updateTime` action with the new complete time instead of just days and hours.

Mostly I just want to fix your useless `switch` statement! It's just `time + value`.

Generally it's not a good idea to have the same data in multiple places.  You can already access the `gmDay` and `gmTime` from your Redux state.  Why not use that directly? It actually doesn't seem like you are using the component state at all here except to calculate the numbers for `updateTime`.

Here's how you can use `Date` to increase by any number of hours, positive or negative.  You can go back or forward multiple days.  The month and year are totally arbitrary and don't matter since we don't use them.

```
const handleTime = (value) => {
  const date = new Date(2000, 0, gmDay, gmTime);
  date.setHours(gmTime + value);
  dispatch(updateTime(date.getDate(), date.getHours()));
};
```

In this particular component we don't need to handle every possible case since we know that `value` is always between 1 and 24.  So some simple math is ok here, but it's less flexible.

```
const handleTime = (value) => {
  const day = gmDay + ( value + gmTime > 24 ? 1 : 0 );
  const time = ( gmTime + value ) % 24;
  dispatch(updateTime(day, time));
};
```

All that your component needs is this:

```
const TimeButtons = () => {
  const { gmDay, gmTime } = useSelector((state) => state.time);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleTime = (value) => {
    const day = gmDay + (value + gmTime > 24 ? 1 : 0);
    const time = (gmTime + value) % 24;
    dispatch(updateTime(day, time));
  };

  return (
    <div className="timeButtons">
      <div className="timeButtons__row 1">
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(1)}>
          1 Hour
        </button>
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(3)}>
          3 Hour
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="timeButtons__row 2">
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(8)}>
          8 Hour
        </button>
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(24)}>
          Next day
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much that really solved all the problems I had, dam I didn't even think of using redux state directly... and the function you made is soooo much simpler. Thank you so much for your help really appreciate it!!! And no I'm saving the values in the data base as an object, not as timestamps, so that works perfectly! Again thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can dispatch the action in a `useEffect` whenever either `day` or `time` values change:

```
//Redux
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { updateTime } from "../../Redux/actions/timeActions";
import { useEffect } from "react";
//Styles
import "./TimeButtons.css";

const TimeButtons = () => {
  const { gmDay, gmTime } = useSelector((state) => state.time);

  const [day, setDay] = useState(gmDay);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(gmTime);

  console.log(day, time);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  if (time > 23) {
    setTime(0);
    setDay(day + 1);
  }

  const handleTime = (value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 1:
        setTime(time + 1);
        break;
      case 3:
        setTime(time + 3);
        break;
      case 8:
        setTime(time + 8);
        break;
      case 24:
        setTime(0);
        setDay(day + 1);
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Error");
    }

  };


  useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(updateTime(day, time));
  }, [day, time]);


  return (
    <div className="timeButtons">
      <div className="timeButtons__row 1">
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(1)}>
          1 Hour
        </button>
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(3)}>
          3 Hour
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="timeButtons__row 2">
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(8)}>
          8 Hour
        </button>
        <button className="button" onClick={() => handleTime(24)}>
          Next day
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TimeButtons;
```

Comment: ohhh man, why did I not think of that..... Thank you for the tip that makes so much sense!!!!